# asymptotic of ratio between two summations (l1 / l2 norm)

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $B$ as a $n\times n$ matrix where
$$B_{ij}(\pmb{\theta})=(\theta_i-\theta_j)\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j), 1\leq i<j\leq n$$ and other entries equals to $0$, and $$\theta=[\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n]\in\{\theta | |\theta_i-\theta_j|\leq \pi/2, \forall i,j\} \setminus \{ \theta | |\theta_i-\theta_j| = 0 \forall i,j\}.$$
Let $b(\pmb{\theta})$ as the below $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$-dimensional vector
\begin{equation}\label{b}
[(\theta_1-\theta_2)\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2),
\cdots,
(\theta_1-\theta_n)\sin(\theta_1-\theta_n),\\
(\theta_2-\theta_3)\sin(\theta_2-\theta_3),
\cdots,
(\theta_2-\theta_n)\sin(\theta_2-\theta_n),\\
(\theta_3-\theta_1)\sin(\theta_3-\theta_1),
\cdots,
(\theta_3-\theta_n)\sin(\theta_3-\theta_n),\\
\cdots,
(\theta_{n-1}-\theta_n)\sin(\theta_{n-1}-\theta_n)]^T
\end{equation}

From numerical experiement, we observe that the ratio between the $l_1$ norm and $l_2$ norm grows at least $n^{1.7}$

Consider the example $\theta=[\pi/2,0,\cdots,0]$ given by @Iosif Pinelis, we modify the conjecture to **at least $n-1$**, or modify the question to **How to estimate the asymptotic value of this ratio?**.

$$\frac{\|b\|_1^2}{\|b\|_2^2}=\frac{\Big(\sum_{i<j}(\theta_i-\theta_j)\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Big)^2}{\sum_{i<j}(\theta_i-\theta_j)^2\sin^2(\theta_i-\theta_j)}\geq n^{1.7}$$

However I have no idea how to prove it.

I would appreciate any hint/help/comment!

[image]

(Numerical experiment: for each $n$, we sample $1000$ number of $\theta$ and compute the ratio $\frac{\|b\|_1^2}{\|b\|_2^2}$ on these $\theta$. Then take the average of the obtained ratios. Thus, in the figure, each blue dot represent the average of ratios on $1000$ samples $\theta$, corresponding to $n$. Here $n$ ranges from $4$ to $500$. The ratio shows a growth at least $n^{1.7}$.)

What I tried:

Take the log to obtain $$$$

Comment: how are the parameters $\theta_i$ distributed?

Comment: sorry, $\theta=[\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n]\in\{\theta | |\theta_i-\theta_j|\leq \pi/2, \forall i,j\} \setminus \{ \theta | |\theta_i-\theta_j| = 0, \forall i,j\}$

Comment: I still don't know how these are parameters are distributed; your plot says "average ratio", how do you average?

Comment: The $\theta$ is located in a half-cirle since for each $i,j$ we have $|\theta_i-\theta_j|\leq \pi/2$. And about the plot, for each $n$, I sampled several $\theta$ in the half-circle region, and compute the corresponding ratio on such $\theta$, since we have $1000$ number of $\theta$ we will have $1000$ number of ratios. Thus I take the average of these ratios and obtained the so called 'average ratio'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This conjecture is not true. E.g., if $\theta_1=\cdots=\theta_{n-1}=0$ and $\theta_n=\pi/2$, then the ratio in question is $n-1$.

Comment: but this is just the value for one particular choice of the angles; for other choices the ratio will scale with $n^2$, and the question is to explain why on average a scaling intermediate between $n$ and $n^2$ is obtained.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Please reread the question: "that the ratio between the $l_1$ norm and $l_2$ norm grows at least $n^{1.7}$ [...] However I have no idea how to prove it. " There is no averaging mentioned in the question. Averaging is only mentioned in the description of a numerical experiment.

Comment: I updated my question to **How to estimate the asymptotic value of this ratio?**.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker In my experiment, the variance of those ratios is very small actually, so this is why I think the ratio should larger than around $n^{1.7}$, maybe 'with high probability'.

Comment: @chloe : One should not change the question so as to invalidate a valid answer. Doing so is disrespectful to efforts of answerers and can discourage them from answering your questions in the future. Instead, one can post the changed question separately, which can also attract more views of the new question. In this particular case, the $\ge n-1$ conjecture seems interesting and perhaps even worthy of posting on MathOverflow.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! I have posted the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450216/asymptotic-of-ratio-between-l1-l2-norm-of-a-structured-vector)