# Asymptotic of ratio between l1 / l2 norm of a structured vector

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

As suggested in this [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450172/asymptotic-of-ratio-between-two-summations-l1-l2-norm), I would like to inquire about the following question:

Consider a matrix B of size $n\times n$ defined as:

$$B_{ij}(\pmb{\theta})=(\theta_i-\theta_j)\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j), 1\leq i<j\leq n$$ where other entries are equal to 0. The vector $b(\pmb{\theta})$ is defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
b(\pmb{\theta}) = \left[(\theta_1-\theta_2)\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2), \ldots, (\theta_1-\theta_n)\sin(\theta_1-\theta_n), (\theta_2-\theta_3)\sin(\theta_2-\theta_3), \ldots, (\theta_2-\theta_n)\sin(\theta_2-\theta_n), \ldots, (\theta_{n-1}-\theta_n)\sin(\theta_{n-1}-\theta_n)\right]^T,
\end{equation}

where $\pmb{\theta} = [\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n]$ satisfies $|\theta_i-\theta_j|\leq \pi/2$ for all $i,j$ and $\theta_i-\theta_j\neq 0$ for all $i,j$.

The ratio of interest is defined as:

$$\frac{\|b\|_1^2}{\|b\|_2^2}=\frac{\Big(\sum_{i<j}(\theta_i-\theta_j)\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)\Big)^2}{\sum_{i<j}(\theta_i-\theta_j)^2\sin^2(\theta_i-\theta_j)}$$

I am interested in studying the asymptotic behavior of this ratio. In my numerical experiments, I sample $1000$ sets of $\pmb{\theta}$ uniformly from the set ${\theta \mid |\theta_i-\theta_j|\leq \pi/2, \forall i,j}$ and compute the ratio $\frac{|b|_1^2}{|b|_2^2}$ for each set. I then take the average of these ratios. The resulting figure displays the average ratios as blue dots, corresponding to different values of $n$ ranging from $4$ to $500$.

[image]

From the figure, it appears that the ratio grows at least as fast as $n^{1.7}$ for the uniformly sampled $\pmb{\theta}$. However, we can also observe that when $\pmb{\theta}=[\pi/2,0,\ldots,0]$, the ratio is equal to $n-1$. This implies that the ratio grows faster than $n^{1.7}$ is not universally true. Given the numerical experiments with uniformly sampled $\pmb{\theta}$ and the specific case where the ratio is $n-1$, **my question is**:

*How does the ratio behave for 'most' points $\pmb{\theta}$ in the set ${\theta \mid |\theta_i-\theta_j|\leq \pi/2, \forall i,j}$? (I am very unsure how to define 'most points'. This statement is the intuition obtained from numerical experiments, it seems that although the ratio can take small value such as $n-1$, most of ratios are actually much larger than that.*

I would appreciate any hints and thank you in advance!

Comment: [Guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer) suggest "avoid trying to answer questions which [...] request answers to multiple questions". Especially in this case, your first question, "How does the ratio behave for all points", is way too open, since the behavior of the ratio may vary very broadly. So, I suggest removing your first question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Make sense! thank you. I've removed it.

Comment: are you interested in the expectation value of this ratio? (for uniformly distributed angles, as in your plot)? I thought that was also what you intended when you asked this question first, at https://mathoverflow.net/q/450172/11260

Comment: @CarloBeenakker For my purpose, yes, and then I need to prove the ratio concentrates on its expectation.

Comment: you might in that case make that more precise in your question, specifying the distribution of the angles that you choose; the expectation value will likely depend on the distribution considered.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Is it possible to derive the asymptotic behaviour of the ratio considering all $\theta$ in the region? My initial question actually is for all $\theta$ rather than considering them to be random vector. My experiment is sampling $\theta$ uniformly, thus it might suggest that ratio grows quicker than $n^{1.7}$ on uniformly distributed $\theta$, however there is no reason to deny the possible fact that the ratio grows on all $\theta$ in the region.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Besides, If consider the function $(\theta_i-\theta_j)sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)$ changed to be $\theta_i-\theta_j$, then the ratio indeed grows at least $n-1$ for all $\theta$, by some calculation&manipulations on the ratio. Thus I am thinking maybe there is a clever way to derive the asymtopics of ratio on all $\theta$. If there is no way to do so, then I might need to consider random $\theta$, but then this might cause issue on my original problem (where the ratio problem comes from).

Comment: @chloe : Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\th\theta$Suppose that the $\th_i$'s are i.i.d. random variables each with a non-degenerate distribution. Then
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\|b\|_1}{\binom n2}=U_n:=\frac1{\binom n2}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}h(\th_i,\th_j),
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\|b\|_2^2}{\binom n2}=W_n:=\frac1{\binom n2}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}h(\th_i,\th_j)^2,
\end{equation*}
where $h(\th_i,\th_j):=(\th_i-\th_j)\sin(\th_i-\th_j)$.

So, $U_n$ and $W_n$ are [U-statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-statistic). So,
\begin{equation*}
    EU_n=c_1:=Eh(\th_1,\th_2), \quad EV_n=c_2:=Eh(\th_1,\th_2)^2,
\end{equation*}
and, in view of a formula by Hoeffding (see e.g. [Theorem 3.4](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Edoksum/STAT709/n709-33.pdf)), $Var\,U_n=O(1/n)$ and $Var\,V_n=O(1/n)$. So, by Chebyshev's inequality,
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\|b\|_1}{\binom n2}=U_n\to c_1
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\|b\|_2^2}{\binom n2}=W_n\to c_2
\end{equation*}
in probability (as $n\to\infty$).

Thus, for the ratio in question we have
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\|b\|_1^2}{\|b\|_2^2}=\frac{U_n^2}{V_n}\binom n2\sim\frac{c_1^2}{c_2}\binom n2 \tag{1}\label{1}
    \sim cn^2  
\end{equation*}
in probability, where $c:=\frac{c_1^2}{2c_2}$.

Moreover, by (say) [Theorem 2.3.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037837589290025N), asymptotic equivalence \eqref{1} holds almost surely.

Furthermore, by (say) the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality, $U_n^2\le V_n$. So, by dominated convergence,
\begin{equation*}
    E\frac{\|b\|_1^2}{\|b\|_2^2}\sim cn^2.   
\end{equation*}

---

E.g., if each of the $\th_i$'s is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$, then
\begin{equation*}
    c_1=\frac{4 (4-\pi)}{\pi ^2},\quad c_2=\frac{3}{\pi ^2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{48}-\frac{1}{4},
\end{equation*}
and hence $c=0.233\dots$.

Shown below are 8 realizations of the (connected) random graph
$\Big\{\dfrac{U_n^2}{2cV_n}\colon n\in\{1,\dots,20\}\Big\}$ (note that, by \eqref{1}, $\dfrac{U_n^2}{2cV_n}=\dfrac{\|b\|_1^2}{2c\|b\|_2^2}\big/\displaystyle{\binom n2}
\sim\dfrac{\|b\|_1^2}{\|b\|_2^2}\big/\displaystyle{(cn^2)}\to1$):

[image]

We see that, in accordance with asymptotic equivalence \eqref{1} holding almost surely, all the 8 realizations are rather close to $1$ even for $n$ as small as $10$.

Comment: Thanks losif! I have a problem when understanding the plot: from (1) we see that $\frac{U_n^2}{V_n}$ grows similar to $n^2$
 asymptotically. why the lines in the plot decreases when n increases? Another question is, in my problem, actually $\theta$
 are sampled in $[-/2,/2]^n$
 asymptotically, instead of that $\theta_i$
 are sampled in $[-/2,/2]$
 asymptotically.

Comment: @chloe : (i) By (1), $\frac{U_n^2}{V_n}$ does not grow, but instead goes to $2c$. So, when we divide $\frac{U_n^2}{V_n}$ by $2c$, the limit of $\frac{U_n^2}{2cV_n}$ becomes $1$. I have now added the detail: "note that, by \eqref{1}, $\dfrac{U_n^2}{2cV_n}=\dfrac{\|b\|_1^2}{2c\|b\|_2^2}\big/\displaystyle{\binom n2}
\sim\dfrac{\|b\|_1^2}{\|b\|_2^2}\big/\displaystyle{(cn^2)}\to1$". (ii) What do you mean by "actually $\theta$ are sampled in $[−\pi/2,\pi/2]^n$ asymptotically"? Can you describe this sampling in formal mathematical terms?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification for question (1). Sorry, for (2) I meant by $\theta$ are sampled in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]^2$ uniformly. So, if every $\theta_i$ are independent, then this is equivalent to $\theta_i$ are sampled in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, is it correct? My follow-up question is, can we derive the similar analysis on $\theta$ are sampled from a certain distribution?

Comment: @chloe : (i) There is no $\theta$ in my answer. So, I don't know what you mean by $\theta$. (ii) Avoid terms like "sample" altogether. Instead, used defined, rigorous  mathematical terms such as "i.i.d. random variables". (iii) As I said in the beginning of the answer, the $\th_i$'s can be any i.i.d. random variables each with any non-degenerate distribution. However, to get a specific value of the constant $c$, we need to  specify the mentioned distribution -- as was done in the example at the end of the answer. Please let me know if anything in the answer is still unclear.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. what I meant is: $\theta=[\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n]$.

Comment: @chloe : I still don't understand your penultimate comment. Please address **all* the points in my previous comments. That includes avoiding such unclear terms as "sample".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147103/discussion-between-chloe-and-iosif-pinelis).

Comment: @chloe : Sorry, I do not get involved in such chat.